# Joining Non-Distinct and Distinct Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using MS SQL SERVER 2008

I have the following scenario below:

```
===================
|     Table A     |
===================
|id      |desc      |code 
| 1      |ballpen   |1010
| 2      |pencil    |1010
| 3      |stabilo   |1010
| 4      |pins      |1011
| 5      |clips     |1011

===================
|      Table B    |
===================
| id     |code
| 1010   |AAA
| 1011   |BBB
| 1013   |CCC
```

What I need to accomplish is something below:

```
===================
|      Table C    |
===================
|id   |desc    |code  |code 2
| 1   |ballpen |1010  |AAA
| 2   |pencil  |1010  |AAA
| 3   |stabilo |1010  |AAA
| 4   |pins    |1011  |BBB
| 5   |clips   |1011  |BBB
```

Here's what I have so far, unfortunately the `LEFT JOIN` is causing the final query output to bloat

```
select *
from table a
  left join table b on a.code = b.id
```

Result:

```
========
Table D
========
|id |desc    |code |code2
|1  |ballpen |1010 |AAA
|1  |ballpen |1010 |AAA
|1  |ballpen |1010 |AAA
|2  |pencil  |1010 |AAA
|2  |pencil  |1010 |AAA
|2  |pencil  |1010 |AAA
|3  |stabilo |1010 |AAA
|3  |stabilo |1010 |AAA
|3  |stabilo |1010 |AAA
|4  |pins    |1011 |BBB
|4  |pins    |1011 |BBB
|5  |clips   |1011 |BBB
|5  |clips   |1011 |BBB
```

Comment: Which table is the distinct one? A or B?

Comment: @StuartLC, Table B is the distinct, Table A have a distinct value but the connection between A and B is Table B.code

Comment: [I can't repeat this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a65f/2) with the data you've posted. Left join just guarantees that all rows in the left table are considered at least once. Table D looks more like a `CROSS JOIN` (or 'comma join') between A and B giving the cartesian product.

Comment: Something is wrong with your question. When I put your sample data and SQL into a fiddle, it works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a65f/3 Note that I did change the SQL as the syntax as given is incorrect (both tables are called `table` in your sample).

Comment: like @Turophile said your query is working fine [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49897/5)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:I think u have used same table name in join.let try using different table name**
I have used Left Join it works..

```
create table #master
(
ID int,
descs varchar(15),
code int
)
create table #codes
(
ids int,
codes varchar(15)
)


insert into #master values(1,'ballpen',1010)
insert into #master values(2,'pencil',1010)
insert into #master values(3,'stabilo',1010)
insert into #master values(4,'pins',1011)
insert into #master values(5,'Clips',1011)

insert into #codes values(1010,'AAA')
insert into #codes values(1011,'BBB')
insert into #codes values(1013,'CCC')


select ID,descs,code,codes from #master a
 left join #codes b
 on a.code = b.ids
```

Output:

```
ID  descs   code  codes
1   ballpen 1010   AAA
2   pencil  1010   AAA
3   stabilo 1010   AAA
4   pins    1011   BBB
5   Clips   1011   BBB
```

In case left join not works for you use  Inner join:

```
select ID,descs,code,codes from #master a,#codes b
where a.code=b.ids
```

Comment: your last method use `cross join` not `inner join`, but final output will be same as with `inner join` but with bad perfomance. also data from `table b` will be missed in case when a.code = b.id will not matched. your left join same as in OP and in case when code in table b will be duplicated will be same issue as in OP

Answer (score 0):

You should try a inner Join

```
       SELECT 
       distinct  a.id,a.desc1,a.code,b.code as code2
           from  a
           inner join  b
           on a.code = b.id
```

Comment: this method use the `cross join` (not `inner join` as you mentioned) poor performance and will be missed data from `table a` in case when `a.code = b.id` will not matched. and in case when `code` in `table b` will be duplicated will be same issue as in OP

Comment: Ok then i will replace it with inner join

Comment: yes, but this still will not give solution for OP, solution is to get unique, it can be done by using subquery or cte with `row_number()` function to get the first antry of the `code`, or using `distinct` as in my post. due to OP need left join

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `table B` contains not unique `code`, so you need to do `distinct` of the selected dataset

here the test:

```
--Create temp tables for data sample 
--table A - unique ID
DECLARE @tableA AS TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      [DESC] VARCHAR(20) ,
      code BIGINT
    )
INSERT  INTO @tableA
        ( id, [DESC], code )
VALUES  ( 1, 'ballpen', 1010 ),
        ( 2, 'pencil', 1010 ),
        ( 3, 'stabilo', 1010 ),
        ( 4, 'pins', 1011 ),
        ( 5, 'clips', 1011 )
--table B not unique code
DECLARE @tableB AS TABLE ( id INT, code VARCHAR(10) )
INSERT  INTO @tableB
        ( id, code )
VALUES  ( 1010, 'AAA' ),
        ( 1011, 'BBB' ),
        ( 1013, 'CCC' ),
        ( 1010, 'AAA' ),
        ( 1011, 'BBB' ),
        ( 1013, 'CCC' ),
        ( 1010, 'AAA' ),
        ( 1011, 'BBB' ),
        ( 1013, 'CCC' )
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--1 variant of the final query
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        a.id ,
        a.[DESC] ,
        a.code ,
        b.code AS [code 2]
FROM    @tableA AS a
        LEFT JOIN @tableB AS b ON a.code = b.id
--2 variant of the final query
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT  DISTINCT
                    a.id ,
                    a.[DESC] ,
                    a.code ,
                    b.code AS [code 2] ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.id ) AS RN
          FROM      @tableA AS a
                    LEFT JOIN @tableB AS b ON a.code = b.id
        ) AS t
WHERE   rn = 1
--3 variant of the final query
;WITH cte AS
   ( SELECT  DISTINCT
                    a.id ,
                    a.[DESC] ,
                    a.code ,
                    b.code AS [code 2] ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.id ) AS RN
          FROM      @tableA AS a
                    LEFT JOIN @tableB AS b ON a.code = b.id
        )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE   rn = 1
--4 variant of the final query
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
        a.id ,
        a.[DESC] ,
        a.code ,
        b.code AS [code 2]
FROM    @tableA AS a
        LEFT JOIN @tableB AS b ON a.code = b.id
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.id )
```

below screenshot of the result:

[image]